# How to find the current width of an element in Angular if an element is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Assume that the below code is a horizontal navbar:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="navItem in totalNavItems">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul,li {
display:inline-block;
}
```

And it gets the values from this json data:

```
var totalNavItems = [{"name":"Item 1"},{"name":"Item 2"},{"name":"Item 3"}];
```

Once the page loads, it populates the DOM with the all the items in the array. Then I get the width of the parent element like so (yes, I'm using jQuery also):

```
$(element).parent().width();
```

Then, for instance I take away one of the items after taking the above width measurement.

```
totalNavItems = totalNavItems.slice(0,2);
```

Now, how do I get the updated width value of the parent?

(I'm writing the angular codes inside a directive link, btw)

Comment: If you are using jQuery, just select the parent again with jQuery after slicing the array, and calculate the width again. You can use a class or a id to select the that parent element you selected before.
`totalNavItems = totalNavItems.slice(0,2); $('...').width();`
You may need to insert it into a timeout? `$timeout(() => $(...).width());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it will work:-

```
totalNavItems = totalNavItems.slice(0,2).then(function () {
   $(element).parent().width();
});
```

use call back `.then` function.